# Incorporating interval-censored event times into standard survival models

Tags: survival

I am trying to model the time until some event occurs for individuals observed over a 24 month period.

For about 75% of people, no event occurs. For 15% of people, we know exact time of the event. For the other 10%, we only know a time window in which it occurs. So some sample "survival times" might be:

```
>24 
2.5 
>24 
5.0 
0 to 6
6 to 12 
>24 
18 to 24
```

and so on. Can this type of data be accommodated within "standard" survival models? If so, some hint at how to construct the `Surv()` object in `R` and how to pass it to `survreg` would be appreciated.

Comment: Now you can post an answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem. Yes, you can do this within classical models and it is simple to do this using the `survival` package in R.

In constructing the `Surv()` object, you need to use the code `3` for the `event` argument to `Surv()`, in conjunction with `type='interval'`. Here's a simple example where the first 50 observations have no "event" within 24 months, the second 50 have exactly known event times and the last 50 only have 6-month windows:

```
x <- rnorm(150)
time <- c(rep(24,50), ceiling(24*runif(50)), ceiling(18*runif(50)))
time2 <- c(rep(24,50), time[51:100], time[101:150]+6)
status <- c( rep(0,50), rep(1,50), rep(3,50) )  
a <- Surv(time, time2, status, type="interval")
model <- survreg(a ~ x, dist="exponential")
```

I did some simulations to verify that this does recover the population structure correctly, even if all of the event times are interval censored (`p=1` below).

```
n <- 1000 # sample size
p <- .5 # proportion of event times (when event time is known) that are interval censored 

# simulate baseline waiting time of 50 and covariate effect of 1. 
t <- rexp(n, rate=1/50)
x <- rnorm(n) 
t <- t*exp(x) 

# censor everything after 24. 
w <- which(t>24) 
t[w] <- 24 
status <- rep(1,n)
status[w] <- 0

# randomly pick some ones to interval censor and generate a random window around them
w <- which(status==1) 
s <- sample(w,floor(p*length(w)))
status[s] <- 3 
ot <- t
t[s] <- floor( t[s]-6*runif(length(s)) ) 
t1 <- t 
t2 <- t
t2[s] <- t2[s] + 6 
t1[ which(t1<=0) ] <- 1e-10 
t2[ which(t2<=0) ] <- t1[which(t2<=0)] + 6

# fit the model. 
a <- Surv(t1, t2, status, type="interval")
model <- survreg(a ~ x, dist="exponential")
print( c(exp( coef(model)[1] ), coef(model)[2] ) ) # should be about 50 and 1.
```